# How to avoid floating point exceptions in unused SIMD lanes

Tags: floating-point, clang, simd, floating-point-exceptions, sigfpe

I like to run my code with floating point exceptions enabled.
I do this under Linux using:

```
feenableexcept( FE_DIVBYZERO | FE_INVALID | FE_OVERFLOW );
```

So far so good.

The issue I am having, is that sometimes the compiler (I use clang8) decides to use SIMD instructions to do a scalar division. Fine, if that is faster, even for a single scalar, why not.

But the result is that an unused lane in the SIMD register can contain a zero.

And when the SIMD division is executed, a floating point exception is thrown.

**Does that mean that floating point exceptions cannot be used at all if you allow the compiler to use sse/avx extensions?**

In my case, this line of C code:

```
float a0, min, a, d;
...
a0 = (min - a) / (d);
```

...is exectuted as:

```
divps  %xmm2,%xmm3
```

Which then throws a:

```
Thread 1 "noisetuner" received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
```

Comment: Does clang have an equivalent for GCC's `-ftrapping-math` to make FP exceptions a visible side-effect?  (Note that GCC's version of that option is on by default, but is actually broken: it fails to stop GCC from doing some optimizations that change the number or type of of FP exceptions, possibly including from 0 to non-zero IIRC.)

Comment: clang doesn't complain when I feed it `-ftrapping-math` but it doesn't fix it. To stop the FPE, I have to supply `-mno-mmx -mno-sse` arguments.

Comment: File a bugreport.

Comment: Are you sure it generates a `divps` and not a `divss`? Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @chtz Not OP but it's very easy to repro, see there: https://godbolt.org/z/Wd98eG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have found a bug in clang or maybe in llvm.

[Here’s how I have reproduced](https://godbolt.org/z/Wd98eG), clang 10.0 emits the same code i.e. has that bug as well. Clearly, that `vdivps` instruction only has valid data in the initial 2 lanes of the vectors, and in the higher 2 lanes it will run 0.0 / 0.0, thus you’ll get a runtime exception if you enable these interrupts in `mxcsr` register like you’re doing.

Microsoft, Intel and gcc don’t emit `divps` for that code. If you can, switch to gcc and it should be good.

**Update:** Clang 10+ has an option controlling such optimizations, `-ffp-exception-behavior=maytrap`, take a look: https://godbolt.org/z/WG7bEE

Comment: Note that gcc misses that optimization even with `-fno-trapping-math` and `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS OFF` https://godbolt.org/z/bGoe1n.  So unfortunately even when you do want the optimization, you can't get it with GCC.  (Even with `-ffast-math`, actually).  Ironically, storing x and y to a `dst[0]` and `dst[1]` output array (making divps an even better optimization, no shuffle needed) defeats both clang and GCC's auto-vectorizer.

Comment: Looks like clang could easily avoid this by replacing both `movsd` by `movddup` (which at least on not too old architectures has the same port usage).

Comment: @chtz: oh good point, yes on Nehalem and later (and some AMD I think/hope), `movddup` is a pure load with the broadcast handled by the load port, no vector ALU.  That would require special exception-safe vectorization support to look for, which may not succeed enough of the time to be worth looking for (given the cost in compile time).

Comment: The -ffp-exception-behavior=maytrap flag makes this issue go away on clang-10. Thanks.